# Nesting Hyper-V with a VM (i.e. Docker Windows Desktop within a VM)?

Tags: docker, hyper-v, hypervisor

On a physical server with Windows Server 2019 Enterprise, I created Hyper V multiple VMs, both Servers and Win 10 Pro client.

I installed Docker Desktop (for Windows) on one of the Win 10 Pro VM clients.

The client virtual machine name is the Hyper-V Manager. I get an error when I try to start DockerDesktopVM, and the state remains off; any Docker command crashes Docker.

**My questions:**

- Is there a conflict when nesting Hyper-V managers and VMs on the physical box?
- How can you execute any docker commands when the DockerDesktopVM is off and cannot be started?

Comment: I've run Docker Desktop for Windows within several different Win 10 VMs and never had a problem.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/enable-nested-virtualization/

Q: How Do I Enable Nested Virtualization for Hyper-V Virtual Machines
A: Pass $true for Set-VMProcessor’s “ExposeVirtualizationExtensions” parameter

```
Set-VMProcessor <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Docker FAQ

> Docker Desktop is not supported in nested virtualization scenarios. It
> might work in some cases and not in others.

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/general/#can-i-run-docker-desktop-in-nested-virtualization-scenarios

Answer (score 0):

It should work even on AMD, according to [`MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation` issue 1276](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/1276):

> ### "[Run Hyper-V in a Virtual Machine with Nested Virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization)"
>
> #### Prerequisites
>
> ...
> AMD EPYC/Ryzen processor or later
>
> - The Hyper-V host must be Windows Server 2022/Windows 11 or greater
> - VM configuration version 10.0 or greater

And:

> ### [What's new in Windows Server 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/whats-new-in-windows-server-2022)
>
> Nested virtualization is a feature that allows you to run Hyper-V inside of a Hyper-V virtual machine (VM).
>
> Windows Server 2022 brings support for nested virtualization using AMD processors, giving more choices of hardware for your environments.
> More information can be found at the [nested virtualization documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization).